# PHP random unique identifier

Tags: php, url, random, uniqueidentifier

In the construction of our booking system client can view their bookings online. At the moment the URL of their page is created as a sequential number. So `/booking1`, `/booking2`, `/booking3` etc...

I'd rather have unique name a bit like the JSFiddle way of doing it. A series of letters and numbers.

Is that possible?

Comment: You've asked the exact same question already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422065/php-random-url-names-short-url.

Comment: Not exactly. And I also did not get a simple answer that I could work with. Thanks for the vote

Comment: Why have you marked it as accepted then?

Comment: Because at the time it answered the initial question but on further development their had to be an easier way of doing it. Thanks for the vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[uniqid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Would uniqid be good enough for what you need?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use `uniqid("bookingr", false);`